# How to change on click action to go to link instead of inputting text

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

So, I am using the [AJAX Live Search PDO](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php) 
I changed the backend-search to link the displayed words.  The problem is if you click on the table that it doesn't take them to the link, but just inputs the text.  I want to be able to link the entire row...  so if they do not just click on the searched word.

I read over the [document](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-ajax-live-search.php) very thoroughly and did not find the answer.

I think it either is on the JavaScript on line 62 of search-form.php, or one the backend-search.php

I added

```
<a href=\"" . $row["link"] . "\"> to the backend-search file.
```

***search-form.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Live MySQL Database Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: Arail, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Formatting search box */
    .search-box{
        width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"]{
        height: 32px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .result{
        position: absolute;        
        z-index: 999;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"], .result{
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Formatting result items */
    .result p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-top: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .result p:hover{
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search country..." />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**backend-search.php**

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo", "root", "");
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Attempt search query execution
try{
    if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
        // create prepared statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name LIKE :term";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';
        // bind parameters to statement
        $stmt->bindParam(":term", $term);
        // execute the prepared statement
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<p><a href=\"" . $row["link"] . "\">" . $row["name"] . "</a></p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
        }
    }  
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Close statement
unset($stmt);

// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
```

I would like when a person clicks anywhere on the row of the results that it goes to the link.  Currently they have to click on the hyperlink

Comment: Put an event listener in the row. and use in it this directive : 
window.location = "URL";

Comment: I am not sure how to add an even listener.  could you explain more?

Comment: The EventListener interface represents an object that can handle an event dispatched by an EventTarget object, Like this one : `$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){}) `  => Something will process when you press a key in your input.  `$(document).on("click","<row selector>",function (){window.location="url"})`  => the navigation will process when you click on the element

Comment: If it still seems unclear i will post an answer later if no one does.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by making the 'a' tag fullwidth(display:block) or cover the 'p' tag with 'a', that will make the whole row clickable.

Comment: tried both, but when click the link i have a targeted iframe on the page to display the link.  Either way, when i click the link the search box doesn't disappear

Answer (score 0):

Here it's a rough example of what you should do. Run the snippet below to check the results (the second link google is not working, it's due to stackoverflow, but if you use on your side, it will work)

```js
$(document).on("click", ".result p", (event) => {
 var url =$(event.target).find("a").prop("href"); // getting the clicked element with event target.
 window.location = url;
})
```

```css
p {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">
  <p><a href="https://stackoverflow.com"> stack</a></p>
  <p><a href="https://google.com"> google</a></p>
</div>
```

I bind the event on the document for various reason. Yours links will be create with a script after the html (DOM) was loaded. Using document permit to bind the event "click" on all ".result p" element even if you add it in the dom after the loading of the page.

```
$(".result p").click(() => {
   var url =$(this).find("a").prop("href"); 
   window.location = url;
});
```

It will target the same element. But it will bind only to ".result p" element that already exist on your html. Note : with this way the clicked element is "this" and not "event.target", because in the previous event, "this" refers to "document".